# rendering a page with data

Tags: node.js, json, express

when i open the page i want i

s to render it and according to the data changing it as i wanted but when i use fetch to get it is said i give incorrect json and i send the html code.

i want after open menu page to render the menuPage.ejs and using the dishes data sent from the side server to show all my dishes.

this is the code when getting to the url i want:
(this part works for sure)

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const { DishModel, validateDish } = require("../models/dishModel")


router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const dishes = await DishModel.find({})
        console.log(dishes);
       // res.render('menuPage')
        res.render("menuPage",  {dishes} );
        //res.json(dishes)
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: "Failed to fetch dishes." });

    }
})
```

now this is the code on the ejs:

```
   fetch("/menu")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        renderDishes(data.dishes);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error fetching dishes:", error);
        errMessage.textContent = "Error fetching dishes.";
      });
```

and i get this error: Error fetching dishes: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON.

edit:
i devided it into 2 separate part and it works.i will show the code but still i'd to know if there is a way to do it the way i showed above.

2 separate gets:

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const dishes = await DishModel.find({})
        res.render("menuPage");
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: "Failed to fetch dishes." });

    }
})

router.get('/onLoad', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const dishes = await DishModel.find({})
        res.json({dishes:dishes})
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: "Failed to fetch dishes." });

    }
})
```

and the fetch:

```
fetch("/menu/onLoad")
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    renderDishes(data.dishes);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error fetching dishes:", error);
    errMessage.textContent = "Error fetching dishes.";
  });
```

this way it works.

Comment: try removing `.then((response) => response.json())`, this method is used for json payload